# selenium - how to select a hyperlink in a table based on the displayed name of the hyperlink

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

I have a table which lists records (school districts in my case).

I want to use Selenium to select the delete icon (the eight td) for the district that is in a row with a certain name, in my case, the name `QA__run` being in the first `td`

How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
//table[@id='districts']//tr//td//a[contains[text(),'QA__run (Selected)']]
```

and

```
//table[@id='districts']//tr//td//a[contains[text(),"*QA__run*"]]
```

but neither selector worked.

So far the best I have is:

```
//table[@id='districts']//tr//td
```

to select the first td of the first tr but that's not specific enough

The table looks like:  [image]

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML and not just a screenshot, this gives not much information about the structure. But it should be something like `//table[@id='districts']/tr[contains(td[1]/a/text(),"QA__run")]/td[8]//a`

Comment: I believe @dirkk's answer is correct. Although, it could be optimized if the anchor tag had some easily identifiable attribute / property you could use instead of moving to the 8th `td` in `td[8]`. Something like `td/a[some_attribute_check]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the `td` with the text first, then go back to the ancestor `tr`, get the 8th `td` in that `tr`.

```
//table//tr//td//a[text() ='QA__run']//ancestor::tr//td[8]
```